# How to create ricardian clauses in the ABI with eosiocpp

Tags: abi, eosiocpp, ricardian

I couldn't find any information on how to automatically include the ricardian clauses in the abi.
I always get the error:

`abi_generator.hpp:68          ricardian_contracts  ] Warning, no ricardian clauses found for`

I found out that the name must be `${contract}_rd.md`.  But the abi_generator doesn't even resolve the correct contract name in my contract.

1. How is the contract name determined?  It looks like you need to use the `EOSIO_ABI` macro in some way. How to do it when I cannot use this macro?
2. I tested it with the example contract: `eosiocpp -n hello` and create files for `hello_rc.md`, `hello.hi_rc.md`. Running `eosiocpp -g hello.abi hello.cpp` creates the abi with no warnings, but the clauses are empty in the `abi` file. Why are they empty? Do they need a specific format?

Comment: There is a python script in the scripts directory for creating RCs with ABIs.https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/scripts/abi_to_rc

Comment: Any way to do it with eosiocpp?

Comment: If there is a flag for creating rc's with eosiocpp, I do not know it.

Comment: eosio-cpp cannot find the ricardian files, no matter what I tried. The -R path does not help. The eosio-init produces the same result ( "empty ricardian clause file") (BTW the message is wrong, it means the CONTRACT.contracts.md file not found) All the official examples do not work either... I even tried to debug the eosio-cpp to find the problem, but the eosio.cdt does not compile on Ubuntu... Not good... Can anyone actually compile a contract with ricardian files?

Answer (score 1):

The `eosiocpp` compiler was the old deprecated way of compiling the c++ into wasm contracts.

The new way uses a compiler called `eosio-cpp`, which is very confusing.

With `eosio.cdt`, you can generate a CMake build system using `eosio-init`, and it will generate the cmake command `target_ricardian_directory`, where you should specify your ricardian contract files. These will then be automatically integrated into the compiled ABI file.